# jQuery oddity in Wordpress

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I'm getting started with Wordpress and trying to use jQuery as my JavaScript library of choice. I've got it loading with `wp_enqueue_script` but for some reason when the page actually loads the `$` function it does so with it behaving like it does in Prototype (single dollar sign is "get by Id" and `$$` is the CSS selector system).

I'm very confused as to why because I cannot find anywhere in the response from the server where the instruction to load Prototype is coming from; there is no `<script>` tag in the head or body that points to the library, and Firebug's list of loaded scripts does not include it. Has anyone else encountered this issue, and if so where is Prototype hiding?

**Update**

After having an idea, I tried something - the `$` and `$$` behavior is part of Wordpress's copy of jQuery 1.4.2: Loading the script from Google's CDN resolved the problem. So the new question is, "Why does Wordpress jQuery differ from normal jQuery?"

Comment: A link to the page might be helpful. Just because it "acts" like Prototype, doesn't mean it is; maybe another script is implementing the `$` and `$$` behaviour.

Comment: It's not live yet, unfortunately. However, the only script the site claims to be loading is jQuery v1.4.2, so even if it's not Prototype something is still not right.

Comment: What's the source URL for the script? Have you checked the contents of it? Are there *any* other scripts on the page?

Comment: Originally the URL was auto-generated by Wordpress using `wp_enqueue_script`; however, removing that call and instead using the Google CDN fixed the problem. No other scripts are being loaded by the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "Why does Wordpress jQuery differ from normal jQuery?"

WordPress loads jQuery in [no conflict mode](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) - another script on the page must've been tinkering with the `$` surely?

Comment: That was my thinking, but I cannot figure out where *that* script is coming from. I even looked to see if for some perverse reason Prototype had been included inline, but it hasn't...

Answer (score 0):

Some things I might try in order to debug this:

- Save Page As -> Web page, complete. Search the resulting directory for "Prototype".
- Then start tinkering with your saved copy of the page. You could insert `<script>` tags at various points in the head of the document, trying to figure out at what point `$` is set, or at what point its behavior changes.
- Or, in Firefox, use `this.watch("$", function () { alert(Error().stack); })` to see where it is set.